# contextSource() is undefined for the type PasswordCompareConfigurer?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm learning *Spring in Action*。I have a trouble when I'm reading the Chapter 4.2.3.

```
package tacos.security;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
                .userSearchBase("ou=people")
                .userSearchFilter("(uid={0})")
                .groupSearchBase("ou.groups")
                .groupSearchFilter("member={0}")
                .passwordCompare()
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
                .passwordAttribute("passcode")
                .contextSource()
                .root("dc=tacocloud,dc=com");
                
    }
}
```

Spring Tool Suite IDE tells me that The method contextSource() is undefined for the type LdapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer.PasswordCompareConfigurer. I'm sure that I didn't copy the code from book incorrectly. Where is error? How should I correct my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem. adding ".and()" before ".contextSource()" can be effective.